# how to get NSData from video file on disk

Tags: ios, nsdata

Given a url like this:

```
file:///private/var/mobile/Applications/C133BAE7-0CBC-4E4F-826B-509B5E1EB68E/tmp/uzhMyDkL0mSI-SCVideo-Merged.mov
```

How can I get the NSData representation of this to send to a server? I've tried all of these:

```
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[url absoluteString]];
NSData *videoData = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:[url path]];
```

`videoData` is nil every time.

EDIT:
For more context I am trying to use [SCRecorder](https://github.com/rFlex/SCRecorder) to capture video.

```
- (void)recorder:(SCRecorder *__nonnull)recorder didCompleteSegment:(SCRecordSessionSegment *__nullable)segment inSession:(SCRecordSession *__nonnull)session error:(NSError *__nullable)error {

    [session mergeSegmentsUsingPreset:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality completionHandler:^(NSURL *url, NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil) {
            //NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
            //NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[url absoluteString]];
            NSData *videoData = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:[url path]];

        } else {
            NSLog(@"Bad things happened: %@", error);
        }
    }];

}
```

Comment: How did you get the URL?

Comment: is it ok you have three slashes in the beginning or URL?

Comment: @heximal - the third slash in the `file:///` scheme is actually specifies the root directory of the device file system.  Think of it as referring to "`/private/var/mobile...`"

Comment: @rmaddy see edit for context.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I understand that but there was always just two slashes in url of any kind whether it http:// or file://. first slash is a kind of separator for url scheme and the second relates to root directory

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant The OP also tried `dataWithContentsOfURL:`.

Comment: You are using a 3rd party library here. See if there is a known issue. Also, be sure to check the `error` parameter on the `recorder:didCompleteSegment:inSession:error:` method.

Comment: You said "...specifies the root directory of the device file system." I don't think an app has access to that due to the app sandbox. This is probably a "you can't get there from here" problem.

Answer (score 1):

The file URL looks correct to me but to be really sure, you should add in this method before trying to fetch NSData:

```
NSError *error = nil;
if ([url checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError: &error] == FALSE)
{
    NSLog(@"URL %@ is not available because %@", [url absoluteString], [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

You can also try fetching the file via:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url
                              options: NSDataReadingUncached
                                error:&error];
if (videoData == nil)
{
    NSLog(@"URL %@ is not available because %@", [url absoluteString], [error localizedDescription]);
} else {
    // you've likely got data, since videoData is not nil!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is weird, but it works if I do this:

```
- (void)recorder:(SCRecorder *__nonnull)recorder didCompleteSegment:(SCRecordSessionSegment *__nullable)segment inSession:(SCRecordSession *__nonnull)session error:(NSError *__nullable)error {

    [session mergeSegmentsUsingPreset:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality completionHandler:^(NSURL *url, NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil) {
            [self getDataFromUrl:url];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Bad things happened: %@", error);
        }
    }];

}

- (void)getDataFromUrl:(NSURL *)url {
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url
                                              options:NSDataReadingUncached
                                                error:&error];
    if (videoData == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"URL %@ is not available because %@", [url absoluteString], [error localizedDescription]);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"GOT IT");
    }
}
```

`videoData` is now valid NSData. Any explanation on why this works if separated into a different method?

Comment: What happens if you get rid of that `getDataFromURL:` method and just call `dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:` inside the `mergeSegmentsUsingPreset:` method directly?

Comment: It works. So `dataWithContentsOfURL` doesn't work, but `dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:` does...

Comment: It may have to do with the option you are passing in. It may have to do with the size of the file. How big is the file?

Comment: videoData.length is 273319